# Uploading an executable file to an aws S3 bucket fails all the time with OptionsRequestDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

Repro with firefox, edge: every time I try to upload a .exe file through AWS S3 portal it's failing. The only error I'm seeing is OptionsRequestDenied. I can't get more details. My account has all permissions. I've tried with different executables a same result. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

This Error is related to Client Browser, related to below 3 things which are blocking traffic from Amazon S3

1. Cookies -  might me cookies disabled on your broswer
2. Firewall - might be firewall blocking
3. Network Connection- might be low internet interrupting connection

Doing below things may resolve your issues.

```
- Disable - Prevent cross-site tracking.  
- Turn off  tracking blocker extension like adBlocker, uBlock etc. 
- Mark/enable/select - All cookies Allowed
```

Or Try to uploading file through AWS Command Line..

Comment: Thank you! Is there a good way to get meaningful logs that OptionsRequestDenied. I disabled cross-site tracking, enable all cookies and still seing the same issue.

Comment: Interesting enough it doesn't work through aws cli on my computer but it does in a container I deploy to aws. Thanks again.